# Wiring JTAG correctly

Tags: stm32, jtag, st-link

I'm a bit confused how to correctly wire JTAG input and output.

I have my ST-Link and my STM32 microcontroller.

Which of the configurations is correct?

Pinout St Link  ||  STM32

TDI----------------->TDI
TDO<---------------TDO
TCK<-------------->TCK
TMS<-------------->TMS
RST---------------->RST

Pinout St Link  ||  STM32

TDI----------------->TDO
TDO<---------------TDI
TCK<-------------->TCK
TMS<-------------->TMS
RST---------------->RST

Comment: Hook it up TDI to TDI and TDO to TDO and so on an so fourth

Comment: Coincidently I had the same question this evening but with a different micro. On my hardware it was TDI to TDI. swapping TDI and TDO is unlikely to cause damage.

Comment: Thanks! @Kartman good to know